# Database connection pooling and connection.close()

Tags: database

In the scenario where a connection is got from a database pool(like Commons DBCP, etc) and when the connection is closed using connection.close(), how is the connection returned to the pool?

Is there come callback method in connection object which is called on connection.close() which returns the connection back to the pool from which it originated?

Comment: why do you ask? Isn't it sufficient that the connectionn is returned to the pool?

Comment: What is wrong with trying to know how things work?

Comment: because the reason people ask such question is usually because they are trying to do something which is not recommended!! But I'm sure you are not...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually the connection object you receive is a decorator of the original one and calling `close` simply returns it to the pool. It does not close it.

Comment: yes, that was the question and the answer is correct. The pool returns a connection that encapsulates the real one and calling close() on it simply returns the object to the pool. The underlying connection is closed by other means (pool management)