# In Python, how to make sure database connection will always close before leaving a code block?

Tags: python, nested, database-connection

I want to prevent database connection being open as much as possible, because this code will run on an intensive used server and people here already told me database connections should always be closed as soon as possible.

```
def do_something_that_needs_database ():
    dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=args['database_host'], user=args['database_user'], passwd=args['database_pass'], db=args['database_tabl'], cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
    dbCursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM table')
    row = dbCursor.fetchone()
    if row['total'] == 0:
        print 'error: table have no records'
        dbCursor.execute('UPDATE table SET field="%s"', whatever_value)
        return None
    print 'table is ok'
    dbCursor.execute('UPDATE table SET field="%s"', another_value)

    # a lot more of workflow done here

    dbConnection.close()

    # even more stuff would come below
```

I believe that leaves a database connection open when there is no row on the table, tho [I'm still really not sure how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091986/database-connection-pooling-and-connection-close).

Anyway, maybe that is bad design in the sense that I could open and close a DB connection after each small block of `execute`. And sure, I could just add a `close` right before the `return` in that case...

But how could I always properly close the DB without having to worry if I have that `return`, or a `raise`, or `continue`, or whatever in the middle? I'm thinking in something like a code block, similar to using `try`, like in the following suggestion, which obviously doesn't work:

```
def do_something_that_needs_database ():
    dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=args['database_host'], user=args['database_user'], passwd=args['database_pass'], db=args['database_tabl'], cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
        dbCursor = dbConnection.cursor()
        dbCursor.execute('SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM table')
        row = dbCursor.fetchone()
        if row['total'] == 0:
            print 'error: table have no records'
            dbCursor.execute('UPDATE table SET field="%s"', whatever_value)
            return None
        print 'table is ok'
        dbCursor.execute('UPDATE table SET field="%s"', another_value)
        # again, that same lot of line codes done here
    except ExitingCodeBlock:
        closeDb(dbConnection)
    # still, that "even more stuff" from before would come below
```

I don't think there is anything similar to `ExitingCodeBlock` for an exception, tho I know there is the *try* `else`, but I hope Python already have a similar feature...

Or maybe someone can suggest me a paradigm move and tell me this is awful and highly advise me to never do that. Maybe this is just something to not worry about and let MySQLdb handle it, or is it?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The traditional approach is the `try`/`finally` statement:

```
def do_something_that_needs_database ():
    dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(host=args['database_host'], user=args['database_user'], passwd=args['database_pass'], db=args['database_tabl'], cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    try:
       # as much work as you want, including return, raising exceptions, _whatever_
    finally:
       closeDb(dbConnection)
```

Since Python 2.6 (and 2.5 with a `from __future__ import with_statement`), there is an alternative (although `try`/`finally` still works perfectly well!): the `with` statement.

```
with somecontext as whatever:
   # the work goes here
```

A context has an `__enter__` method, executed on entry (to return the `whatever` above, if you want) and an `__exit__` method, executed on exit.  Despite the elegance, since there is no existing context that works the way you want, the work needed to build one (although reduced in 2.6 with `contextlib`) should probably suggest that good old try/finally is best.

If you have 2.6 and want to try `contextlib`, this is one way you could do it to "hide" the try/finally...:

```
import contextlib

@contextlib.contextmanager
def dbconnect(**kwds):
  dbConnection = MySQLdb.connect(**kwds)
  try:
    yield dbConnection
  finally:
    closeDb(dbConnection)
```

to be used as:

```
def do_something_that_needs_database ():
    with dbconnect(host=args['database_host'], user=args['database_user'], 
                   passwd=args['database_pass'], db=args['database_tabl'], 
                   cursorclass=MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as dbConnection:
       # as much work as you want, including return, raising exceptions, _whatever_
```

It may be worth it if you are going to use this many, many times, just to avoid repeating the try/finally over and over for each of those many uses.

Comment: oh well, after you and Michael edited your answers we've got 2 very similar and complete ones... hard to choose.

Comment: in one hand, i hope my choosing didn't affect @michael stunning losing "score" so much (88k vs 781k). in the other hand, looks like i did choose "the champion"!  crazy scoring dudes.

Answer (score 6):

If MySQLdb supports it, then you could use the "[with](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343)" statement. The "with" statement exists for just that reason. However, it requires that the object define __enter__ and __exit__ for that to work.

As an example of the with statement... for reading/writing files, you might have:

```
with open('filename','r') as file:
    for line in file:
        # processing....
# File automatically closed afterwards or if there was an exception thrown
```

If it doesn't support it, then you can always use try...finally as in:

```
try:
    # Do some processing
finally:
    # Cleanup
```

The finally clause is executed no matter how the try finishes (whether it completed successfull, or an exception was propagated but caught, or an exception was thrown and will continue to propagate).

Comment: I recently tried that with pyodbc and it didn't work, but you might have better luck.

Comment: It shouldn't be too tough to author the appropriate calls though in a wrapper, if your particular object doesn't support it already.  The cited pep even shows you how to do it for files.

Comment: That's very interesting to know, but I don't think it's supported by MySQLdb. It definitely isn't by Python 2.5

Comment: necro heads up. i haven't read anything, i hardly do any coding today... but looks like this continues to be relevant! 

Answer (score 4):

Why not just wrap it in a try: finally: block?

http://docs.python.org/tutorial/errors.html#defining-clean-up-actions

This is what finally blocks are for.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the DB driver you're using doesn't support `with` out of the box, try [the `closing` method from `contextlib`](http://docs.python.org/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.closing).